# How to exclude the quotes(") inside the columns of CSV exports generated from DBeaver

Tags: java, csv, export-to-csv, dbeaver

I tried to take a csv export of my database results set to a CSV from the Dbeaver.I want to get the output without any quotes inside the columns but there should be quotesand at the start of a row and at the end (including header).

e.g - "Header1|Header 2|Header 3|"

But what I'm getting from the DBeaver is either having quotes at the start of a row and also inside some of the columns(and not at the end) or get it without a single quote.Below mentioned are the two options that I have observed.

e.g -
option 1 -
"Header1|"Header 2"|Header 3|

option 2 -
Header1|Header 2|Header 3|

I couldn't find an option to remove the inside quotes. Any thoughts on this?
Should I look for a different approach? I have attached a photo of the settings section.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: configuration setting]

- Characters escape: `escape`
- Quote character:

Notice that Quote character is not empty, it is a single space.

Answer (score 0):

Try .strip('""')

Example:

a_string = '"ab"cd"'

stripped_string = a_string.strip('"')

print(stripped_string)

OUTPUT

ab"cd